# ServiceNow integration with Airflow

Tags: airflow, scheduler, servicenow, tivoli-work-scheduler

Can we integrate ServiceNow with Airflow ? I mean if there is any DAG failure, can we rerun the failed DAG/tasks by submitting a ServiceNow request ? Also can we submit an adhoc job to run using ServiceNow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I heard that ServiceNow use a turnkey rest api for integration. Any idea if AirFlow has that capability or not ?

Comment: https://github.com/Cloud-Innovation-Partners/miniBRS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply use the on_failure_callback parameter of the dag to call a function that makes a POST request using service now's SET API (particularly the u_incident table)